# External monitor via HDMI goes black randomly, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, brightness, 19.10

I'm connecting an external monitor, via HDMI, to my Lenovo running a **Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)** and **GNOME 3.34.2**.

The monitor switches to black, or even a dimmed brightness view, simply randomly.

After reading some other posts, for older ubuntu versions, I've reduced the refresh rate for both monitors as well as try to not have the audio thru the HDMI.

Does anyone experiences this and/or have any suggestion?

Thank you very much`

Comment: Static electricity on my HDMI cable will cause screen to turn off for a second.